# Folder not being created

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a field/name from a form submitted and create a folder out of it and it seems to go through without errors but it doesn't create a folder.

My HTML:

```
<form id="roomcreation" name="roomcreation" method="post" action="/">
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="roomcreation"><p>
Room Name:<p>
<input class="roomcreation_text" name="roomname" type="text" id="roomname";">
<p>File Name:<p>
<input class="roomcreation_text" name="filename" type="text" id="filename";">
<p>Editor Password:<p>
<input class="roomcreation_text" name="editorpassword" type="password" id="editorpassword";"><p>
<p>Genre Select:<p>
  <select name="genre" id="genre" onChange="javascript:chgAction()">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="Creative">Creative</option>
  <option value="Erotic">Erotic</option>
  <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
  <option value="Gorean">Gorean</option>
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="Reality">Reality</option>
  <option value="Supernatural">Supernatural</option>
  <option value="Transilient">Transilient</option>
  </select>

<?php echo $error_message; ?><p>

<input class="roomcreation_button" type="submit" name="create" value="Create Room" id="roomcreate";">
</form>
```

my php:

```
<?php
// 
if (isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['editorpassword']) && isset($_POST['roomname']))

$dir  = $_POST['filename']; // This must match the "name" of your input
$path = "evo/$dir";
if (!file_exists('$path')) {
mkdir('$path', 0755, true);
}

print_r($_POST); exit; //

?>
```

**update**

I changed my directory that I tried to ouput to, being the same one the script is currently in, evo/$dir and it inserted a folder called $path, meaning it did not pick up the filename variable and as I had it previously written it is not writing to the directory I wanted it to go to, which is /rooms/creative/$dir.

Comment: is this parent directory path `rooms/creative` ?

Comment: can you debug it using set using  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: May be there is chance of Permission.

Comment: as for the parent path, no rooms/creative is in a different location from where the .php file is

Comment: Check that the webserver has the necessary permissions on the filesystem and turn on error reporting.

Comment: doublechecked permissions as far as I can tell have never had problems writing script or saving with necessary permissions elsewhere and far as I can tell error reporting is one but its not bringing me back anything.

Comment: check to see if the path is writable in the first place `if (!is_writable($path)) { print "$path is not writeable"; }`

Comment: also, echo the value of `getcwd()` to make sure it's attempting to create the dir from the correct relative path

Comment: Hey Clayton thanks for the help I put the if writeable line right after my make directory line and it did the same thing, it didn't echo or return anything, I'm unsure if that was the wrong place to put it, and am not sure where I could write < echo getcwd() > (and if that is correct)

Comment: Ok I figured that out, when I echo it, its showing /home/revo/public_html/evo which is the folder where its trying to create the directory from (ie: where the script is located) the directory we want to create is /home/revo/public_html/rooms/creative/(filename here)

Comment: and having the is writeable in there went through, and did not return path is not writeable

Comment: be carefull here, '$path' results in $path not getting the content of the variable path but $path as string. To get the content of the variable use double quotes, here in the file_exists and the line beneath. So as you've mentioned the directory permissions seem to work, as the folder with the name $path is being created

Comment: thank you Tobias, it was the way I was writing the path and variables it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form**

```
<form id="roomcreation" name="roomcreation" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="roomcreation">
    <p>
        Room Name:
        <input class="roomcreation_text" name="roomname" type="text" id="roomname">
    </p>
    <p>
        File Name:
        <input class="roomcreation_text" name="filename" type="text" id="filename">
    </p>
    <p>
        Editor Password:
        <input class="roomcreation_text" name="editorpassword" type="password" id="editorpassword">
    </p>
    <p>
        Genre Select:
        <select name="genre" id="genre" onChange="javascript:chgAction()">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="Creative">Creative</option>
            <option value="Erotic">Erotic</option>
            <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
            <option value="Gorean">Gorean</option>
            <option value="History">History</option>
            <option value="Reality">Reality</option>
            <option value="Supernatural">Supernatural</option>
            <option value="Transilient">Transilient</option>
        </select>
    <p>
    <?php echo $error_message; ?><p>
        <input class="roomcreation_button" type="submit" name="create" value="Create Room" id="roomcreate">
</form>
```

**Sever-side script**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['editorpassword']) && isset($_POST['roomname'])) {
    $dir = $_POST['filename']; // This must match the "name" of your input
    $path = "evo/" . $dir;
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0755, true);
    }
}
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Try this, if not working change permission to 0777 (Note that 0777 is already the default mode for directories and may still be modified by the current umask.)

I hope this helps.

If you are not sure about the path, use `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: That helps immensely! Thank you Nikhil I knew I was writing it wrong. That however created a new folder called evo/then the directory folder off the filename. That's ok for testing and didn't mess anything up. I need to however make the folder go to is: /home/revo/public_html/rooms/creative/(filename here)  and I'm not sure how to ensure it creates it at that specific place after creative/

Comment: thank you Nikhil I'm not quite sure about ensuring that I have the right path, I know where it needs to go and the path I should say, just not how to direct it there. I'm reading more about it now, thank you.

Comment: I know I have the path wrong, everytime I try something like ./rooms/creative/ . $dir as you have it in there, it creates it in the folder where the script is, rather then finding the correct path.

Comment: Send me the output of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php. Match the output until you get the exact location.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = rooms/creative . '/' . $dir;
```

Replace with:

```
$path = "rooms/creative/$dir";
```

Comment: Thank you Shailesh I did that and its still not creating the folder

Comment: Thank you again Shailesh I'm not sure what I'm missing but its still not creating it and still not getting an error.

Comment: comment your if statement and try it. I think your post variable is not set `$_POST['roomcreation']`

Comment: do you have these two folders `rooms/creative` ?

Comment: no. but I try try your code with my folder structure names and it is working fine.

Comment: I do have those two folders, yes. And I commented out my if statement so it starts just at $dir and it does the same thing. no errors, no creation. You might be right i might be missing that just trying to remember how to set the variables